# Cannot delete a connection on Xero API

Tags: xero-api

I have completed the Xero OAuth flow with the following scopes:

`openid profile email accounting.transactions offline_access`

When I attempt to DELETE a connection using the URI [https://api.xero.com/connections/{xeroTenantId}](https://api.xero.com/connections/%7BxeroTenantId%7D) I get the error **AuthenticationUnsuccessful**.

My access token is valid and I am able to perform a GET on the same endpoint with the same token. There is nothing in the documentation that I can find which explains what scope is required to delete a connection: https://developer.xero.com/documentation/guides/oauth2/scopes

Comment: I've noticed the same issue, [revoking a token](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/guides/oauth2/pkce-flow#revoking-tokens) seems to work but am unable to delete the whole connection.

Comment: I also added the xero-tenant-id header as per: https://developer.xero.com/documentation/guides/oauth2/auth-flow#6-call-the-api, but the issue persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete a connection you need to put the connectionId to the URI and not the tenantId.

```
DELETE https://api.xero.com/connections/{connectionId}
Authorization: "Bearer " + access_token
```

Please see this link

https://developer.xero.com/documentation/guides/oauth2/auth-flow/#removing-connections

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Not sure how I've missed that! Thanks!